# Symlink to webstorm, ain't working

Tags: macos, symlink, webstorm

I've tried doing this:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/webide" /bin/webstorm
```

and then if I run it, it throws

```
013-10-26 15:40:56.191 webstorm[12210:1f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString hasPrefix:]: nil argument'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff895cc41c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff863eae75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff895cc2cc +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff894e572a -[__NSCFString hasPrefix:] + 90
    4   webstorm                            0x0000000100001f03 satisfies + 435
    5   webstorm                            0x000000010000245d findMatchingVm + 1213
    6   webstorm                            0x0000000100003832 -[Launcher launch] + 98
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fff8fdf170b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff847bd899 _pthread_body + 138
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff847bd72a _pthread_struct_init + 0
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff847c1fc9 thread_start + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

So, how do I start webstorm from the terminal?

ps. interestingly if I run it directly it runs

```
"/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/webide"
```

but I prefer something shorter than that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh... I was doing it wrong... There's an option in Webstorm... "Tools -> Create command line launcher"
it works great. I love this IDE. "JetBrains" - you guys are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The code is not expecting to be run from a symlink. Kind of a bug, but an obscure one I guess. You can instead put it on your PATH (or add an alias, but that's not the normal way to solve this problem). Here is how to put it on your PATH -

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

although this might still hit the same bug, I guess. So try it first - if it works, add it to your `$HOME/.bashrc` file.

Comment: easier solution is there.. check my own answer